# Drupal 6 : Programmatically creating nodes for OG..!

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

I am creating nodes pro-grammatically for a portal by fetching emails. But I have got a situation here.

I have some Organic group and every OG has got it's own content type. At start I thought to use different mailbox for each OG.

Now the thing is..how to assign nodes which get create pro-grammatically to particular OG ?

Note :- I am able to create different kind of nodes based on subject of the mail.

Please help..

Comment: At least if some body can help me finding the DB table where values goes for any node creation if it's inside any OG that - the node belongs to this particular OG...then I will try my luck :)

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating the node object set its og_groups property to an array of all the nids of the groups you want it in.  For example if you have a group with nid 4, and you want your node to be in that group do this before calling node_save on it.

```
$node->og_groups = array(4);
```

After saving that node it should be in the og with nid 4.